# SQL query to delete records when the difference between two dates is greater than a certain value

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to delete records when the difference between SYSDATE and a TIMESTAMP (6) field of my table is greater than 10 days. I have created the following query:

```
select (SYSDATE - myDate) as difference from myTable where difference > 10;
```

but i get the following error:

```
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

am i creating the query correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> am i creating the query correctly?

No, you cannot refer to an alias in the `SELECT` clause in the filter condition of the same statement.

Additionally, when you subtract a `TIMESTAMP` from a `DATE` you will get the result as an `INTERVAL` data type; so you need to compare on that rather than a `NUMBER` (which would be the result if you compared `DATE - DATE`).

You want:

```sql
SELECT SYSDATE - myDate as difference
FROM   myTable
WHERE  SYSDATE - myDate > INTERVAL '10' DAY;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6c6db456fea082f375807e593647d52a)*